# How to compute the similarity of an order when compared to the user's previous order?

Tags: sql, postgresql, precision-recall

I want to measure the "similarity" of each order by a customer when compared to their previous order. How much of the current order (e.g o2) overlaps with the previous order (e.g. o1) by computing the [precision and recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) of the current order items when compared to the previous order items(ground truth).

`true positive = number of items present in the current order that's also present in the previous order`

`false positive = number of items present in the current order that's NOT present in the previous order`

`false negative = number of items present in the previous order that's NOT present in the current order`

`precision = true positive / ( true positive + false positive)`

`recall = true positive / (true positive + false negative)`

I have two tables in Postgres named `orders` and `order_items`.

orders:

```
id user_id
o1  u1
o2  u1
o3  u1
o4  u2
o5  u2
o6  u3
```

order_items

```
id  order_id item_id
oi1  o1       i1
oi2  o1       i2
oi3  o1       i3
oi4  o2       i2
oi4  o2       i3
oi5  o3       i3
oi6  o3       i1
```

For the user u1, the order uniqueness results required would be

```
order_id recall precision
o1         0       0         -- recall, precision are zero since it's their first order
o2         1       0.66      -- precision is one because true positive is 2 (i2, i3) and false positive is none. 
                             -- recall is 0.66 because true positive is 2 (i2, i3) and false negative is 1 (i1 is not ordered in the second order o2)
o3         0.5     0.5       -- precision is 0.5 because true positive is 1(i3) and false positive is 1 (i1 - since it was not in the second order o2)
                             -- recall is 0.5 because true positive is 1 (i3) and false negative is 1 (i2 - since it was not in the third order o3)
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Your source tables contain no information related to the given calculations or the desired output.

Comment: @alexherm added a comment to clarify further.

Comment: Perhaps a smallpoint, but language and terms chosen are important to a concept, ecause they tend to stick around. "Uniqueness" is binary; something is either unique or it's not, so you can't calculate "how unique" something is, other than determining whether it is or not, so it doesn't suit "measuring". Perhaps "dissimilar" is a better term, or even better express it in the positive, so "similar", and "simularity" is a concept often used in data science/machine learning so it's probably a better term to use in favour of "uniqueness".

Comment: OP, which part of coding this is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the formulas you need two things:

1. number of items in each order
2. number of common items in the current and previous order

The first one you can calculate by grouping `order_items` by the `order_id`:

```sql
SELECT
    order_id,
    count(*) AS count
FROM order_items
GROUP BY order_id
```

For the common items count you need to join `order_items` with itself. The problem here is: what does 'previous order'
actually mean? Assuming it is based on the `order_id`, it can be obtained with some string manipulation:

```
prev_ordder_id = concat('o', (substring(curr.order_id FROM 2)::Int - 1))
```

The common items count can be calculated now as follows:

```sql
SELECT
    curr.order_id AS curr_order_id,
    prev.order_id AS prev_order_id,
    count(*) AS count
FROM order_items curr
INNER JOIN order_items prev
ON prev.order_id = concat('o', (substring(curr.order_id FROM 2)::Int - 1)) AND prev.item_id = curr.item_id
GROUP BY curr_order_id, prev_order_id
```

Now you can put it all together. The simplest way would be using `WITH` clause:

```sql
WITH items AS (
        SELECT
            order_id,
            count(*) AS count
        FROM order_items
        GROUP BY order_id
     ), common AS (
        SELECT
            curr.order_id AS curr_order_id,
            prev.order_id AS prev_order_id,
            count(*) AS count
        FROM order_items curr
        INNER JOIN order_items prev
        ON prev.order_id = concat('o', (substring(curr.order_id FROM 2)::Int - 1)) AND prev.item_id = curr.item_id
        GROUP BY curr_order_id, prev_order_id
     )
SELECT
    common.curr_order_id,
    common.prev_order_id,
    common.count::decimal / curr.count as precision,
    common.count::decimal / prev.count as recall
FROM common
LEFT JOIN items curr ON curr.order_id = common.curr_order_id
LEFT JOIN items prev ON prev.order_id = common.prev_order_id;
```

And the result:

```
 curr_order_id | prev_order_id |       precision        |         recall
---------------+---------------+------------------------+------------------------
 o2            | o1            | 1.00000000000000000000 | 0.66666666666666666667
 o3            | o2            | 0.50000000000000000000 | 0.50000000000000000000
```